Can you pattern match with eslint - lean-imports/import
I have a resource that is a folder of images. When a user imports an image using the pattern below, it pulls in the whole package.
import {thisIcon} from "../../myResource/dist";

So, I want to put an eslint rule that flags this in the same what that the code below can be used to stop this practice with lodash and similar packages.
"lean-imports/import":[1,[
  "lodash"
]]

The lean-imports package seems to use string matching, so this works for my purposes ...
"lean-imports/import":[1,[
  "lodash",
  "../myResources/dist",
  "../../myResources/dist",
  "../../../myResources/dist",
  "../../../../myResources/dist",
  "../../../../../myResources/dist",
  "../../../../../../myResources/dist",
  "../../../../../../../myResources/dist"
]]

Is there a way to do pattern matching to make this work instead of doing this?
